# Is it possible to order by distance?

Tags: here-api

I'm asking if it's possible to order results by distance in a `Discover` query. I've performed a query for train stations however, the results seem to order somewhat randomly. I'm only interested in what the nearest train station is and so having a result with the nearest distance first would be valuable.

I appreciated that it's entirely possible to programmatically achieve this, but before I burn time working on a solution, I figured it was worth reaching out to see if this was already possible within the API.

If it helps, this is the query I was making `https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=-34.0337365,151.0847004&q=station&limit=10&apikey=`. You may see that the closest result is 4th down.

Happy to hear an alternative solution if there is one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two different ways. 
Use the `browse` endpoint instead of `discover` and the results will be arranged according to distance. The code will look like:

https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=-34.0337365,151.0847004&name=station&limit=10&apikey=

OR

https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=-34.0337365,151.0847004&categories=400-4100-0035&limit=10&apikey=

Places category system
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-places/places-category-system-full.html